# How can I make a suggestion List in my Autocomplete application?

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete

I am making an autocomplete application and the list of my words are coming from my database. I have a textfield and now I want to make a suggestion list that will appear below the field everytime I type something. Could you give me some hint or idea how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, do you have some idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much better if you use JCombobox but if you are using Jtextfield, I would rather suggest to you to use Jlist and put in JWindow since you are using textfield, thats what I've tried in my Dictionary application.

EDIT :

```
public class MainMenu extends JPanel
{

private final Connection connection;

private final Application application;


private JTextField word = new JTextField(10);

private final JButton translate = new JButton();

private final JComboBox translators = new JComboBox();

private final JButton search = new JButton();
private JList speechPartAndDefinitionWidget;

private final DefaultListModel speechPartAndDefinitionWidgetModel = new DefaultListModel();

private Translator translator;
private Suggestor suggestor;

private DefaultListModel translatedWidgetModel;
private JList translatedWidget;

private final DefaultListModel suggestionWidgetModel = new DefaultListModel();
private final JList suggestionWidget = new JList(suggestionWidgetModel);

private JavaWindow javaWindow = new JavaWindow(suggestionWidget);

public MainMenu(Application application, Connection connection)
{

    word.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()
    {
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
        {
            try
            {
                onWordUpdated(word.getText());
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (SQLException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
        {
            try
            {
                onWordUpdated(word.getText());
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (SQLException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
        {
            try
            {
                onWordUpdated(word.getText());
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();

            }
            catch (SQLException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    });


    this.application = application;
    this.connection = connection;

    translators.setFocusable(false);
    word.grabFocus();
    word.requestFocus();
    word.setFocusable(true);

    search.setText("<html><b><u>S</u>earch</b></html>");
    translate.setText("<html><b><u>T</u>ranslate</b></html>");

    translators.addItem(new EnglishBisayaTranslator(connection));
    setToolTipText("English-Bisaya");
    translators.addItem(new BisayaEnglishTranslator(connection));
    setToolTipText("Bisaya-English");

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel formX = new JPanel();
    formX.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel header = new JPanel();
    header.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    header.add(translators);
    header.add(word);
    header.add(search);
    header.add(translate);

    translators.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(1));
    translators.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10));
    word.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    word.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray, 1));
    word.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.BOLD, 17));
    suggestionWidget.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 17));
    header.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 8));


    formX.add(BorderLayout.PAGE_START, header);
    formX.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 15, 10, 10));
    add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    speechPartAndDefinitionWidget = new JList(speechPartAndDefinitionWidgetModel);
   speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
    {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent ev)
        {
            onDefinitionSelected(ev);
        }
    });

    JPanel formBottom = new JPanel();
    formBottom.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    add(formBottom, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Component up = new JScrollPane(speechPartAndDefinitionWidget);
    formBottom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 10, 10, 10));   speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black,1));

    JPanel down = new JPanel();
    down.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    down.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
    down.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));


    down.add(translatedWidget = new JList(translatedWidgetModel = new DefaultListModel()));
    add(down, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    translatedWidget.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
    translatedWidget.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD, 17));
     speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 17));
    add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, up, down));

    word.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
            {
                hideSuggestionWindowToBack();
            }
            else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
                int selectedIndex = suggestionWidget.getSelectedIndex();

                if (selectedIndex == -1)
                {
                    onSearchClick();
                }
                else
                {
                    onSuggestionSelected(selectedIndex);

                }
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
                hideSuggestionWindowToBack();
                onSearchClick();
            }
        }
    });

    translators.addActionListener(new

            ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed
                        (ActionEvent e)
                {
                    onTranslatorsClick();
                }
            }

    );

    word.addKeyListener(new

            KeyAdapter()
            {
                public void keyPressed
                        (KeyEvent
                                 e)
                {
                    if (suggestionWidgetModel.isEmpty())
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                    {
                        final Point location = word.getLocationOnScreen();
                        javaWindow.setLocation(location.x, location.y + word.getHeight());
                        showSuggestionWindowToBack();

                        int currentSelectedItemIndex = suggestionWidget.getSelectedIndex();
                        if (currentSelectedItemIndex == -1 || currentSelectedItemIndex == suggestionWidgetModel.size() - 1)
                        {
                            suggestionWidget.setSelectedIndex(0);

                        }
                        else if (currentSelectedItemIndex < suggestionWidgetModel.size() - 1)
                        {
                            suggestionWidget.setSelectedIndex(currentSelectedItemIndex + 1);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
                    {
                        int currentSelectedItemIndex = suggestionWidget.getSelectedIndex();
                        if (currentSelectedItemIndex == -1 || currentSelectedItemIndex == suggestionWidgetModel.size() + 1)
                        {
                            suggestionWidget.setSelectedIndex(0);
                        }
                        else if (currentSelectedItemIndex < suggestionWidgetModel.size() + 1)
                        {
                            suggestionWidget.setSelectedIndex(currentSelectedItemIndex - 1);

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
    );


    suggestionWidget.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            int selectedIndex = suggestionWidget.getSelectedIndex();

            if (e.getClickCount() == 2)
            {
                if (selectedIndex < -1)
                {
                    onSearchClick();
                }
                else
                {
                    onSuggestionSelected(selectedIndex);
                    hideSuggestionWindowToBack();
                }
            }

        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2)
            {
                {
                    hideSuggestionWindowToBack();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.addKeyListener(new

            KeyAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed
                        (KeyEvent
                                 e)
                {
                    if (speechPartAndDefinitionWidgetModel.isEmpty())
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                    {

                        int currentSelectedItemIndex = speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.getSelectedIndex();
                        if (currentSelectedItemIndex == -1 || currentSelectedItemIndex == speechPartAndDefinitionWidgetModel.size() - 1)
                        {
                            speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.setSelectedIndex(0);

                        }
                        else if (currentSelectedItemIndex < speechPartAndDefinitionWidgetModel.size() - 1)
                        {
                            speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.setSelectedIndex(currentSelectedItemIndex + 1);
                            onTranslate();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
                    {
                        int currentSelectedItemIndex = speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.getSelectedIndex();
                        if (currentSelectedItemIndex == -1 || currentSelectedItemIndex == speechPartAndDefinitionWidgetModel.size() + 1)
                        {
                            speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.setSelectedIndex(0);
                        }
                        else if (currentSelectedItemIndex < speechPartAndDefinitionWidgetModel.size() + 1)
                        {
                            speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.setSelectedIndex(currentSelectedItemIndex - 1);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
    );

    speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
        {
            final int x = e.getX();
            final int y = e.getY();


            final Rectangle cellBounds = speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.getCellBounds(0, speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.getModel().getSize() - 1);
            if (cellBounds != null && cellBounds.contains(x, y))
            {
                speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            }
            else
            {
                speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            }
        }
    }
    );

    speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.setCellRenderer(new

            DefaultListCellRenderer()
            {
                @Override
                public Component getListCellRendererComponent
                        (JList
                                 list, Object
                                value, int index,
                         boolean isSelected,
                         boolean cellHasFocus)
                {
                    final String speechPart = ((DefinitionUiModel) value).getPart().getFriendlyName();
                    final String definition = ((DefinitionUiModel) value).getDefinition().toString();
                    Color bg = null;
                    Color fg = null;

                    final JLabel renderer = new JLabel(
                            "<html><font color=red>" + speechPart + "</font>) => <font color=black>" + definition + "</font></html>");
                    if (renderer.isEnabled())
                    {

                        if (isSelected)
                        {
                            renderer.setText("<html><font color=gray>" + speechPart + "</font><font color=blue><u><b>" + definition + "</b></u></font></html>");
                            renderer.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                        }

                        JList.DropLocation dropLocation = list.getDropLocation();
                        if (dropLocation != null
                                && !dropLocation.isInsert()
                                && dropLocation.getIndex() == index)
                        {

                            bg = DefaultLookup.getColor(this, ui, "List.dropCellBackground");
                            fg = DefaultLookup.getColor(this, ui, "List.dropCellForeground");

                            isSelected = true;
                        }

                        if (isSelected)
                        {
                            renderer.setBackground(bg == null ? list.getSelectionBackground() : bg);
                            renderer.setForeground(fg == null ? list.getSelectionForeground() : fg);
                        }

                        Border border = null;

                        if (cellHasFocus)
                        {

                            if (isSelected)
                            {
                                border = DefaultLookup.getBorder(this, ui, "List.focusSelectedCellHighlightBorder");
                            }
                            if (border == null)
                            {
                                border = DefaultLookup.getBorder(this, ui, "List.focusCellHighlightBorder");
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {

                        }


                    }
                    return renderer;
                }
            }

    );


    translatedWidget.setForeground(Color.black);

    translate.addActionListener(new

            ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed
                        (ActionEvent
                                 e)
                {
                    onTranslate();
                }
            }

    );
    search.setToolTipText("find");
    search.addActionListener(new

            ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed
                        (ActionEvent
                                 e)
                {
                    onSearchClick();

                }

            }

    );
    translators.setSelectedIndex(0);

    suggestionWidget.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray, 1));

    onTranslatorsClick();

}

private void onSuggestionSelected(int selectedIndex)
{
    String hold = (String) suggestionWidgetModel.getElementAt(selectedIndex);
    word.setText(hold);
    hideSuggestionWindowToBack();
    suggestionWidgetModel.clear();


    if (javaWindow == null)
    {
        javaWindow.dispose();
        javaWindow = null;

    }


}

public void onWordUpdated(final String toComplete) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                final List<Suggestion> suggestions = suggestor.getSuggestions(toComplete);

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        speechPartAndDefinitionWidgetModel.clear();
                        translatedWidgetModel.clear();
                        suggestionWidgetModel.clear();
                        try
                        {
                            for (Suggestion suggestion : suggestions)
                            {
                                suggestionWidgetModel.addElement(suggestion.getCaption());
                            }
                            if (!suggestions.isEmpty())
                            {
                                suggestionWidget.setSelectedIndex(0);

                                if (javaWindow == null)
                                {
                                    javaWindow = new JavaWindow(suggestionWidget);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    final Point location = word.getLocationOnScreen();
                                    javaWindow.setLocation(location.x, location.y + word.getHeight());
                                }
                                showSuggestionWindowToBack();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                hideSuggestionWindowToBack();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            exception.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (SQLException e)

            {
                onSqlError(e);
            }
        }
    }
            , "onWordUpdated").

            start();

}

private void onTranslate()
{
    try
    {
        translatedWidgetModel.clear();

        String lookupWord = word.getText();
        if (lookupWord != null)
        {
            Collection<String> bisayaWords = this.translator.translateSimple(lookupWord);

            for (String bisayaWord : bisayaWords)
            {
                translatedWidgetModel.addElement(bisayaWord.toUpperCase());

            }
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        onSqlError(ex);
    }
}

private void onSqlError(SQLException ex)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQL Error! :" + ex.getMessage());
}


private void onDefinitionSelected(ListSelectionEvent ev)
{
    if (!ev.getValueIsAdjusting())
    {
        int selectedIndex = speechPartAndDefinitionWidget.getSelectedIndex();

        if (selectedIndex != -1)
        {
            final DefinitionUiModel definitionUiModel = (DefinitionUiModel) speechPartAndDefinitionWidgetModel.get(selectedIndex);
            translate(definitionUiModel.getDefinition());
        }
    }
}

private void translate(Definition definition)
{
    try
    {
        translatedWidgetModel.clear();

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        int definitionId = definition.getId();
        String definitionName = definition.getValue();


        int nameId = translator.getFromDictionary().getNameIdForDefinitionId(definitionId);

        if (nameId > -1)
        {
            final Collection<String> translation = translator.translateSimple(nameId);
            for (String transWord : translation)
            {
                map.put(transWord, definitionName);

                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
                {

                    String myValue = entry.getKey().toUpperCase() + " -- " + entry.getValue();
                    translatedWidgetModel.addElement(myValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        onSqlError(ex);
    }
}


private void onSearchClick()
{
    search.setEnabled(true);
    hideSuggestionWindowToBack();
    speechPartAndDefinitionWidgetModel.clear();
    translatedWidgetModel.clear();

    try
    {
        final String lookupWord = word.getText();

        if (lookupWord != null)
        {
            final Dictionary fromDictionary = translator.getFromDictionary();

            final WordDefinitions definitions = fromDictionary.getWordDefinitions(lookupWord);

            final Iterator<Map.Entry<SpeechPart, List<Definition>>> items = definitions.iterator();

            while (items.hasNext())
            {
                final Map.Entry<SpeechPart, List<Definition>> item = items.next();

                for (Definition definition : item.getValue())
                {
                    speechPartAndDefinitionWidgetModel.addElement(new DefinitionUiModel(item.getKey(), definition));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        onSqlError(ex);
    }
}

private void onTranslatorsClick()
{
    translator = (Translator) translators.getSelectedItem();
    suggestor = new Suggestor(translator.getFromDictionary(), 10);
    word.setEnabled(true);

    application.setTitle(translator.toString());

    translators.setToolTipText("tooltip : " + translator.toString());

    speechPartAndDefinitionWidgetModel.clear();
}

private void hideSuggestionWindowToBack()
{
    if (javaWindow == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    javaWindow.setVisible(false);
    javaWindow.toBack();
}

private void showSuggestionWindowToBack()
{
    if (javaWindow == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    javaWindow.setVisible(true);
    javaWindow.toFront();
}

}
```

Comment: could you give me some more idea about that?

Comment: you have to create another class for your JWindow and put the suggestions list in JWindow, also maybe you have to locate the x,y coordinates between your textfield and the window.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm (that I know of) behind the suggestions list is: [Longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). The problem is quite easy if you have stored the strings in the database in the form of a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Then the list of suggestions for the current prefix will be all those strings that start with the currently entered string. You will understand what I mean if you look at the Trie data structure.